# Accordion jquery ui error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a problem with jquery ui accordion I put the code that should work in theory but it seems I do something wrong.

```
$("#section ul").accordion({
    event: "mouseover",
    active: "#mainmenu",
    collapsible: false,
    autoHeight: false
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).accordion('activate', "#mainmenu");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/W6Exu/2/

Comment: Try removing the extra comma `autoHeight: false,` <--

Comment: what I want is that default has opened the ID # mainmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jQueryUI accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) docs, active accepts an integer (which is zero based) that should be open.  So try

```
$("#section ul").accordion({
    event: "mouseover",
    active: 1,
    collapsible: false,
    autoHeight: false
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).accordion('activate', "#mainmenu");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W6Exu/3/

Comment: could graduate a question like that nose speed too fast for the hover effect?

Comment: @Raul I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: What I want is to do a little slower effect. Also thanks for the help it has worked your code

Comment: Thanks, tell me if there is any way possible that you first close one and open the tabs selected? because it seems that both opens and closes both simultaneously happening now.